# Firebase Phone number authentication Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

The firebase authentication for mobile authentication that came in yesterday when I try to add its dependency it says:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0
```

I have already connected my project with Firebase but the problem persists.

[this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) documentation link asks to add the dependency above. Also the  [realease notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) link mentions the phone number authentication compatibility has been added in sdk 11.0.0

Comment: same problem here. any update?

Comment: Nope. None of the solutions worked yet.

Comment: The issue has been resolved now @windchime

Answer (score 0):

open Android Studio go to Tools->Firebase->Authentication->Email and Password Authentication->Click Add Firebase Authentication to your app and Sync gradle this will remove the error and add the dependencies to your app

Answer (score 0):

Please Update Your SDK and Play Service. Then Try again.
I hope It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Update your google repository in Android Studio. The dependency will compile succcessfully

Comment: android studio>tools>android>SDK Manager>SDK Tools>Support Repository>Google Repository

Answer (score 0):

remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` from your app level build.gradle file